# Translation of a sentence containing "might"

Tags: traduction, anglais

> With more complex chemical equations, one might be guessing and checking for more than a while.

Deepl donne

> Avec des équations chimiques plus complexes, on peut être en train de deviner et de vérifier pendant plus d'un moment.

Mon expérience m'indique que ça ne sera pas aisément compris par un locuteur natif du français. Des idées pour améliorer la phrase française ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sans contexte il me paraît compliqué de proposer une traduction certaine, mais quoi qu'il en soit la traduction donnée en exemple n'est absolument pas idiomatique et sent le traducteur automatique à plein nez.

Je tenterais quelque chose comme :

> Avec des équations chimiques plus complexes, la résolution pourrait prendre plus de temps (à supposer qu'on parle de la résolution de ces équations)

ou, plus générique sans-doute :

> Avec des équations chimiques plus complexes, cela demanderait plus de temps et d'efforts. (et peu importe ce que le "cela" recouvre)...

et si on peut tomber dans une registre beaucoup moins formel :

> Avec des équations chimiques plus complexes, cela pourrait vite tourner à la prise de tête.

Answer (score 1):

> Avec des équations plus complexes, on mettrait plus de temps à déduire et vérifier.

Me semble être une traduction plus correcte.

Ici *might* est traduit en mettant au conditionnel le verbe *mettre*

Comment: Peut-être "déduire" serait-il plus correct que "deviner" dans le sens où l'on suppose j'imagine un raisonnement logique.

Comment: Effectivement, ce terme fait plus professionnel. Je corrige sur le champ, merci.